# Is there any way to add delay in screen reader announcements in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, screen-readers

I am new to Accessibilities stuff and I am facing issue where I have multiple errors on screen but screen reader announce only last error message. But later I realised reader is reading both errors but it was so quick that unable to announce 1st error and announce only 2nd(last error)

[image]

I tried to solve by putting `aria-live="assertive"`, `aria-relevant="all"`, `role="alert"` but behaviour is still same.

Please do let me know if I can attach more information to elaborate more instead marking negative rating to question.

[image]

Comment: You don’t need `aria-live=assertive`, as its already inherent in the `alert` role. Unfortunately your example only shows one message. Could you provide an actual code sample so that we can more easily reproduce the issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

Different screen readers buffer the text to announce differently. Some will queue all of them up and announce them all in turn, others will try to optimize all the text and might drop some of it in order to keep up. You can't really control that and the screen reader user is used to it.

It also might be affected by the speech rate of the screen reader.  Many users have the rate set very fast and they'll hear everything.  Others have it set slower.

In any event, even if all your error messages are not announced, they should still be associated with the field that's in error (usually with [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby)) so if the user navigates back to the form, they'll hear the error message associated with the field.

You should also set [`aria-invalid="true"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-invalid) on the fields that are in error (and set it to "false" or remove the attribute when the field is corrected).